# Rails controller match one var to another var

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table that has alot of data inside it

I'm wanting to do something like this. To grab everything inside a column that matches something else inside another column in another table.

So `@car = Cardata.find_by(@carmake)`

So, `@carmake` will be volvo, Typed in a separate form and stored in a table.

In the table `Cardata` there is a massive list (about 40k records) with different cars ranging from ford to renault to volvo.

The question is. Would `@car` display all the records that have the word volvo inside?? Or is it the wrong way of doing this? or do i need to label it by column?

Sam

Comment: `find_by` Finds the first record matching the specified conditions.

Comment: if you want to search in mutliple fields with carmake you can create something like this. `Cardata.where('description ilike ? or title ilike ? ', "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%" )`

Comment: Dry way of searching in multiple fields `Cardata.where('description LIKE :search OR title LIKE :search ', search: "%#{search}%")`

Answer (score 0):

To get all of them:

```
@cars = Cardata.where(carmake: @carmake).all
```

To get just the first:

```
@car = Cardata.where(carmake: @carmake).first
```

Comment: I guess `where` by default return `all` we need not to add `.all`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column in car data for `make`, I think you'd want to do something like:

```
@cars = Cardata.where(make: @carmake).all
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be doing:

```
@car = Cardata.find_by_attribute_name(@carmake) # This will return the first car that matches @carmake.
```

Assuming attribute_name is model.

You'd do:

```
Cardata.find_by_model(@carmake)
```

If you want all the cars that matches @carmake.

You need to do:

```
Cardata.where(model: @carmake) # this will return an array of all cars with model @carmake.
```